# ADO.NET edm отсутствует в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ado.net

Вы можете столкнуться с тем, что при попытке добавить к своему проекту в Visual Studio модель **ADO.NET EDM**, вы ее не найдете в списке доступных элементов.
Вы можете попробовать произвести действия указанные ниже, чтобы решить данную проблему.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос как вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, ADO.NET EDM **доступна не для всех проектов** в VS (во всяком случае, сразу). Обратите внимание, какой проект вы создаете. Например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оба приложения - консольные. Однако только в проект слева можно добавить ADO. Если вы хотите сделать консольное приложение, то выбирайте простое консольное приложение для командной строки.

Если указанное действие не помогло, убедитесь, что у Вас установлен Entity Framework. Для этого откройте инсталлер Visual Studio (пуск -> в строку поиска "Visual studio installer"), нажмите "Дополнительно", затем "Изменить". Во вкладке "Отдельные компоненты" проверьте, установлен ли пакет/библиотека "Инструменты для Entity Framework 6". Если его нет - установите.

Не факт, что данные рекомендации помогут именно Вам, но наверняка приблизят Вас к цели.

Comment: А зачем вам EDM в новом проекте в 2020?